# charnames::viacode() for the short name?

Tags: perl, unicode

Is there a version of `charnames::viacode()` which will return the short name of code-point, i.e. the name that can be used when `use charnames ':short'` is in effect?

```
use charnames ':short';

my $x = ord("\N{Cyrillic::es}");

say "long name:  ", charnames::viacode($x); # prints "CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES"
say "short name: ", ???($x);                # want: Cyrillic:es
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[charnames](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?charnames) documents that

```
SCRIPTNAME:CHARNAME
```

searches for

- SCRIPTNAME CAPITAL LETTER CHARNAME (if CHARNAME isn't all lowercase)
- SCRIPTNAME SMALL LETTER CHARNAME (if CHARNAME is all lowercase)
- SCRIPTNAME LETTER CHARNAME

so you could use

```
sub short_name {
   my ($long_name) = @_;
   return "$1:\U$2" if $long_name =~ /^(\S+) CAPITAL LETTER (\S+)\z/;
   return "$1:\L$2" if $long_name =~ /^(\S+) SMALL LETTER (\S+)\z/;
   return "$1:$2"   if $long_name =~ /^(\S+) LETTER (\S+)\z/;
   return $long_name;
}
```